# Automatically installing software on the client machine

Tags: java, automation, webserver, parallel-processing, remote-access

Its more of a design and architecture scenario.

I want to have number of nodes in the cluster and initially all the nodes are pre-installed with java 6 and windows/linux. In all the nodes I want to install my application (this application I will be maintaining on the server) and this application will be used to run the some tasks on parallel.

On server I want to monitor traffic of all the nodes and task execution status.

So how to achieve it?

Any comments on this will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AndrewThompson : edited to find question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly you can use [parallel-ssh](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) and its [pscp and pssh](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/execute-commands-simultaneously-on-multiple-servers-using-psshcluster-sshmultixterm.html) commands to copy your distrib onto the remote hosts and run commands you want to install it.

There are also some alternatives: [dsh](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en), [clusterit](http://www.garbled.net/clusterit.html)